# How to get node app running on Amazon EC2 instance to start on reboot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, node.js, elastic-beanstalk, rc.local

So I have Node/Express app running on an Amazon Linux Ec2 instance (VPC). The path to my node app is as follows `/home/ec2-user/server/server.js`

If I run `which forever` I get

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/bin/forever
```

If I run the following command the node app starts and works.

```
forever start server.js
```

If I reboot the server or stop/start then server.js will not run. I have to run forever start server.js from the terminal.

I tried the following ways to get my app to restart with forever and it will **NOT** restart.

**rc.local**

```
forever start ../home/ec2-user/server/server.js

./.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/bin/forever start ../home/ec2-user/server/server.js
```

**/init/kue.conf**

```
description "start kue server"

start on filesystem and started networking
stop on shutdown

script
  touch /var/log/forever.log
  touch /var/log/stat_out.log
  touch /var/log/stat_err.log
  rm /var/log/forever.log
  rm /var/log/stat_out.log
  rm /var/log/stat_err.log
  forever start -l /var/log/forever.log -o /var/log/stat_out.log -e /var/log/stat_err.log /home/ubuntu/code/StatKue/server.js
end script
```

**crontab -e**

```
forever start /server/server.js
```

None of these works and I have spent 3 days trying to get forever to restart my app on reboot?

Comment: Why are you trying to use forever instead of just a normal systemd unit?

Comment: Forever is used for node applications. I have also tried pm2 but it also only works if I manually run the command.

Comment: I know what forever and pm2 are. They're generally not necessary on modern systems unless you're deploying into a Docker container though.

Comment: Either way the issue I believe is that where I put the call, any call to start the app it doesn’t seem to find the path. I have tried ../ ./ ~/ and local. Not sure if is a permissions issue or what?

Answer (score 0):

In your rc.local use the absolute path to the server.js and the forever binary. Also make sure the rc.local is executable, `chmod 755 rc.local`